# Docker permission error while up

Tags: shell, docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im using the following `dockerfile` to `build and run` go application
the application name is `book-store` and it's located under `go/src/book-store` in my local `mac`.

```
go
-src
--book-store
--main.go
```

Now i've create the following docker file

```
FROM golang:1.9.6-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git

RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin


ENV SOURCES /go/src/book-store
COPY . ${SOURCES}


RUN cd ${SOURCES} && CGO_ENABLED=0 go build

RUN chmod +x /go/src/book-store

WORKDIR ${SOURCES}
CMD ${SOURCES}
EXPOSE 8080
```

in addition i've create this docker compose

```
version: '2'
services: 
  book-store-web:
    build: .
    image: book-store:1.0.1
    environment: 
    - PORT=8080
    ports: 
    - "8080:8080"
```

Now I use

`docker-compose build`

which created image successfully, and now I want to run the image with 
`docker-compose up`

And I got the following error:

```
Creating book-store_book-store-web_1 ... done
Attaching to book-store_book-store-web_1
book-store-web_1  | /bin/sh: /go/src/book-store: Permission denied
book-store_book-store-web_1 exited with code 126
```

**Any idea what could be wrong here ?**

I've added the `RUN chmod +x /go/src/book-store` to overcome the permission issue without success...

Comment: It appears that you're trying to execute a directory. What directory has the docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cmd line is incorrect it should read:

```
CMD ${SOURCES}/book-store
```

you are trying to execute a directory

Also just as an aside this container is running as root, you should really make it run as a user you create that doesn't have root privs.

You could do this with a Dockerfile that looked a bit like this:

```
FROM golang:1.9.6-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git

RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin

ENV SOURCES /go/src/book-store
COPY . ${SOURCES}

RUN addgroup goapi && \
  adduser -D -S -G goapi goapi && \
  cd ${SOURCES} && \
  CGO_ENABLED=0 go build && \
  chmod +x /go/src/book-store && \
  chown -R goapi:goapi /go

USER goapi

WORKDIR ${SOURCES}
CMD ${SOURCES}/book-store
EXPOSE 8080
```

hope this helps.

Comment: 1+ Can you please elaborate or better, provide example :) how should I improve my dockerfile /compose ? im a bit new to this topic .thanks!

Comment: of course, i added to the answer, obviously check this works for you but it gives you an idea.